# SQL Server - Convert LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME to camel case Firstname Lastname

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

Hi as it states in the title i have names in the format LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME and i wish to have the data in the format Firstname Lastname.  This is going to be used in a OLE DB SOURCE query in SSIS so do not want it in a function.  How can this be done?

Comment: What's with the downvoting??? i have stated very clearly exactly what i need...

Comment: Be careful when converting the case of names.  A good example is [MACDONALD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macdonald).  Both MacDonald and Macdonald are valid last names.  You won't be able to tell which version to use from the raw data alone.  There are many, many more examples with lots of fringe cases.

Comment: I thanks for your comment.  In that situation i wouldn't care if it came out as Macdonald instead of MacDonald...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 declare @NameString Varchar(50) = 'BLOGGS, JOE'

   SELECT  CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',@NameString) = 0 THEN 'Unexpected format: ' + @NameString ELSE 
  UPPER(LEFT( RIGHT( @NameString,len(@NameString)-CHARINDEX(',',@NameString)-1 ),1)) +   --First Initial
   LOWER(SUBSTRING(@NameString,CHARINDEX(',',@NameString)+3,LEN(@NameString))) -- rest of first name


  +' ' +
  UPPER(LEFT(@NameString,1)) -- Surname initial
   + LOWER(RIGHT(LEFT(@NameString,CHARINDEX(',',@NameString)-1),LEN(LEFT(@NameString,CHARINDEX(',',@NameString)-1))-1)) -- rest of surname
   END
```

Comment: when using this i get 'invalid length parameter passed to the left or substring function'.

Comment: do you have any values in your table without a comma?

Comment: that may have been my fault one min.

Comment: I have added a case statement to flag up if this is the case

Comment: excellent, this is working, one more thing can we handle double barrelled last name separated by dash like HESSLING-INDUSTRIAL for example?

Comment: That will be returned as 'Hessling-industrial' , and I suggest the solution is to cope with the lower case 'i'  . You could do it by adding a case statement and using a combination of charindex, replace, left, right substring  functions, but to cater for all possibilities (especially if your users are entering free text) will be convoluted and painstaking.

Answer (score 2):

How can you convert a firstname to camelcase? how would you know where to put the uppercase? if FIRSTNAME is JOE, then what is the camelcase of that? Joe? If that what you mean then you can just do :

```
SELECT UPPER(LEFT(FIRSTNAME,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(FIRSTNAME,2,LEN(FIRSTNAME))) FROM ....
```

Comment: when i said camelcase i meant Joe Bloggs instead of BLOGGS, JOE how it is currently stored...

Comment: this gives same result as @Rahul, lastname does not start with a capital letter.

Answer (score 1):

Another Version but with fewer functions:

```
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR( 100 )
SET @Name = 'LASTNAME, FIRSTNAME'
SELECT
    -- First Name
    UPPER( SUBSTRING( @Name, CHARINDEX( ',', @Name ) + 2, 1 ))
        + LOWER( SUBSTRING( @Name, CHARINDEX( ',', @Name ) + 3, 1000 ))
    + ' '
    -- Last Name
    + UPPER( LEFT( @Name, 1 ))
        + LOWER( SUBSTRING( @Name, 2, CHARINDEX( ',', @Name ) - 2 ))
```

Would be interesting to see how it compares with JamieA answer performance wise, if any difference is noticable.

Comment: this gives error Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 3
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: This will be the missing comma issue.  I would suggest the performance would be the same, as the database engine will use the same execution plan , but +1  as SUBSTRING improves the readability for your answer.  although if I am being really picky, your answer has 'fewer' functions, not 'less'  ;)

Comment: Have mercy on grammatically challenged foreigner :)